# R raster time series stack circular statistics

Tags: r, statistics, time-series, r-raster

I have a   `raster time-series` with values from 1 to 36 representing 10 days (`dekads`) timesteps and NA values. 
I need to calculate the `average` and the `standard deviation`, taking into account that dekads are `circular` (36 is last dekad of the year, 1 is the first ones).

Here below is the code for the average (it seems working) but I am not able to write a code for the standard deviation. 
**Can you please check if the code for the average calculation produces the right outputs and help me in writing the ones for the standard deviation.**

Many thanks

```
require(raster)
r <- raster(ncol=50, nrow=50)
s <- stack(lapply(1:length(r), function(x) setValues(r, values = sample(x = c(0:36),size = ncell(r), replace = T))))

# 0 is set to NA

s[s==0]<-NA

#  function
conv <- 2*pi/36  #SET HERE THE time steps

fun1 <- function(m,na.rm=T){
  x1 = Arg(mean(exp(conv*(m-1)*1i),na.rm=na.rm))
  x2 = x1/conv
  x3 = (x2 + 36) %% 36
  return(x3)
}

# MEAN calculation
s_avg <- calc(s,fun1)
s_avg <- round(s_avg,0)
s_avg <- s_avg + 1
s_avg [s_avg==37] <- 1
s_avg

plot(s_avg)
```

Comment: To compute the mean and std of a time series it should not matter whether they are circular or not; and you can do `s_avg <- calc(s, mean)`. Do you need the moving average (std)? (if so, see ?raster::movingFun)

Comment: Dear Robert,thanks for you comments. In this case I need to use circular stats because data is dates (dekads). ie: if my time-series is 30 (3rd dekad of october) and 3 (3rd dekad of january) the avg is 35 (second dekad of december) and not 16.5.

Comment: Ah, I assumed you wanted to statistics for observations at the dekads, not for the dekads themselves.

Comment: Dear, pixel values are dekad numbers, they are the output  of a processing of rainfall data and represent the rainfall season timings by year. With the piece of code I would like to calculate the stats (avg and std). Thanks